# como saber si una palabra es palindroma o no en javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema q no me sale, el ejercicio es este :

Escribir una función que determine si la cadena de texto que se le pasa como parámetro es un palíndromo, es decir, si se lee de la misma forma desde la izquierda y desde la derecha.

aqui el codigo , porfavor diganme q esta mal q no sale

```
let text ="";
let arrayText=[];
function palindromo(text){
    arrayText= text.split("");
    arrayInvertido=arrayText.reverse();
    if(arrayInvertido==arrayText){
         console.log ("es palindromo");
    }else{
        console.log("no es palindromo");
    }
 
}
palindromo("tombo");
palindromo("reconocer");
```

Comment: Bienvenido, en el sitio ya existe información relacionada, te sugiero revisar : https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+palindromo

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás queriendo comparar arreglos, en vez de el valor de las cadenas en sí. Podemos cambiar esa condición, modificando el `arrayInvertido` a `invertedText` para compararlo con la cadena que se manda por parámetro:

```
function palindromo(text) {
  const invertedText = text.split("").reverse().join("");
  if (text === invertedText) {
    console.log("es palindromo");
  } else {
    console.log("no es palindromo");
  };

};

palindromo("reconocer");
```

Cabe destacar que esta función realiza lo básico, y está sujeto a posibles errores si se manda como parámetro otro valor que no sea string, ya que no estamos haciendo las validaciones adicionales correspondientes.

Answer (score 1):

El arrayText que ocupas en tu condición "if" ya ha sido invertido cuando ocupaste .reverse() con lo cual te conviene ocupar el text original que recibe la función

```
let text = "";
let arrayText = [];
function palindromo(text) {
    arrayText = text.split("");
    arrayInvertido = arrayText.reverse();

    // ocupar text y no el arrayText
    if (arrayInvertido == text) {
        console.log("es palindromo");
    } else {
        console.log("no es palindromo");
    }

}
palindromo("tombo");
palindromo("reconocer");
```